# Changing the defauls key values for JButton in Nimbus LaF

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel, nimbus

I have a two Buttons in my program

```
JButton button1 = new JButton();
button1.setText("First Button");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Second Button");
```

I have tried to change the LaF of the button, I am able to change the button background color using the following code

```
UIManager.put(Button.background new color(134,201,236));
```

But when i tried to change the other key values like `"Button.disabled"`, `"Button[Default+Focused+Pressed].backgroundPainter"` the code did not work for me.
Could someone help me how to change the default key values which uses Painter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gotta love Nimbus.

Okay to start with, you're going to want to keep these values close...

```
Button.background = DerivedColor(color=214,217,223 parent=control offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=214,217,223
Button.contentMargins = javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=6,left=14,bottom=6,right=14]
Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus = false
Button.disabled = DerivedColor(color=214,217,223 parent=control offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=214,217,223
Button.disabledText = DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145
Button.focusInputMap = javax.swing.plaf.InputMapUIResource@70e4bd3a
Button.font = javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=SansSerif,name=sansserif,style=plain,size=12]
Button.foreground = DerivedColor(color=0,0,0 parent=text offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=0,0,0
ButtonUI = javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel
Button[Default+Focused+MouseOver].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@3e5d2085
Button[Default+Focused+Pressed].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@78662669
Button[Default+Focused].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@2988e80b
Button[Default+MouseOver].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@7c508d6d
Button[Default+Pressed].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@2b5ec36a
Button[Default+Pressed].textForeground = DerivedColor(color=255,255,255 parent=nimbusSelectedText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=255,255,255
Button[Default].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@62c2ed06
Button[Disabled].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@c6499e5
Button[Disabled].textForeground = DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145
Button[Enabled].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@742746e1
Button[Focused+MouseOver].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@293f9e9c
Button[Focused+Pressed].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@5ce0ec60
Button[Focused].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@7463fda8
Button[MouseOver].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@3a3dad8b
Button[Pressed].backgroundPainter = javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter@6f231f2e
```

These are basically the default key/values used by Nimbus to paint a standard button...

Basically, what you have to do is provide your own `Painter`, for example...

```
public class ButtonPainter implements Painter {

    private Color light, dark;
    private GradientPaint gradPaint;

    public ButtonPainter(Color light, Color dark) {
        this.light = light;
        this.dark = dark;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, Object c, int w, int h) {
        System.out.println("...");
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        gradPaint = new GradientPaint((w / 2.0f), 0, light, (w / 2.0f), (h / 2.0f), dark, true);
        g.setPaint(gradPaint);
        g.fillRect(2, 2, (w - 5), (h - 5));

        Color outline = new Color(0, 85, 0);
        g.setColor(outline);
        g.drawRect(2, 2, (w - 5), (h - 5));
        Color trans = new Color(outline.getRed(), outline.getGreen(), outline.getBlue(), 100);
        g.setColor(trans);
        g.drawRect(1, 1, (w - 3), (h - 3));
    }
}
```

And then replace the `UIManager` values

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new ButtonPainter(Color.YELLOW, Color.RED));
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Focused].backgroundPainter", new ButtonPainter(Color.YELLOW, Color.RED));
```

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Painter;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;

public class TestNimbus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestNimbus();
    }

    public TestNimbus() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                System.out.println(UIManager.get("Button[Default+Focused].backgroundPainter"));

                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new ButtonPainter(Color.YELLOW, Color.RED));
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Focused].backgroundPainter", new ButtonPainter(Color.YELLOW, Color.RED));

                System.out.println(UIManager.get("Button[Default+Focused].backgroundPainter"));


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(new JButton("First Button"));
                frame.add(new JButton("Second Button"));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ButtonPainter implements Painter {

        private Color light, dark;
        private GradientPaint gradPaint;

        public ButtonPainter(Color light, Color dark) {
            this.light = light;
            this.dark = dark;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g, Object c, int w, int h) {
            System.out.println("...");
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            gradPaint = new GradientPaint((w / 2.0f), 0, light, (w / 2.0f), (h / 2.0f), dark, true);
            g.setPaint(gradPaint);
            g.fillRect(2, 2, (w - 5), (h - 5));

            Color outline = new Color(0, 85, 0);
            g.setColor(outline);
            g.drawRect(2, 2, (w - 5), (h - 5));
            Color trans = new Color(outline.getRed(), outline.getGreen(), outline.getBlue(), 100);
            g.setColor(trans);
            g.drawRect(1, 1, (w - 3), (h - 3));
        }
    }

}
```

This is a global change, so all buttons will be affected by this change.  I believe there's a way to do so only those controls you want to change can be affected, but you will need to do some more research into that yourself ;)

Comment: *"Gotta love Nimbus."*  I think the 'Gotta' part is debatable.  I've considered a PLAF changer combo. that filters Nimbus out.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Personally, I the "system" look and feel for most situations, users seem to accept it better - IMHO

Comment: Yes, the system PLAF would be my first 'default' choice for an app.  If they want to get fancy I'd look to the JGoodies PLAFs, which I feel are clean and subtle.

Comment: After some testing, I got some new doubts related to above code.    1. Is it possible to provide only one color for the ButtonPainter class?                                                           2.Is it possible to get the roundedrectangle for the new color because the default button shape in Nimbus is with rounded edges.                                                            If it is possible Could you please provide me the code? @MadProgrammer

Comment: 1- Yes, 2- Yes.  You control the entire painting process. You could crack open the src.zip in your JDK directory and have a look at how Nimbus does it

Comment: you mean to check ButtonPainter.java? regarding the first question, the GradientPaint() in the code is using the two colors in the implementation. what other methods should i use for my own painter? @MadProgrammer

Comment: You can do anything that the `Graphics2D` API is capable of, `setColor` and `fillRect` come to mind

Comment: thankyou so much for your help. I have managed to solve the problem @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack that works:

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthButtonUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils;

public class FlatButton extends JButton {

    private static final SynthButtonUI UI = new SynthButtonUI();
    private static final SynthGraphicsUtils UTIL = new SynthGraphicsUtils();

    public FlatButton() {
    }

    public FlatButton(Icon icon) {
        super(icon);
    }

    public FlatButton(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public FlatButton(Action a) {
        super(a);
    }

    public FlatButton(String text, Icon icon) {
        super(text, icon);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setPaint(this.getBackground());
        final Dimension d = this.getPreferredSize();
        g2d.fillRect(0,0, d.width, d.height);
        this.paintBorder(g);

        g2d.setColor(this.getForeground());
        g2d.setFont(this.getFont());
        UTIL.paintText(
          UI.getContext(this), g, this.getText(), this.getIcon(),
          this.getHorizontalAlignment(), this.getVerticalAlignment(),
          this.getHorizontalTextPosition(), this.getVerticalTextPosition(),
          this.getIconTextGap(), this.getDisplayedMnemonicIndex(), 0);

    }
}
```