# How to use lookandfeel and also edit it

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

GUI of the Project I'm working on uses Nimbus lookandfeel. 
I can't change it. It effects too much things.
on the other hand, I also need to change lots of color properties.

So I want to use Nimbus and edit some properties

But:

When I use

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
UIManager.installLookAndFeel(info);

UIManager.put("Label.background", colorA);
UIManager.put("Panel.background", colorA);
UIManager.put("CheckBox.background", colorA);
UIManager.put("TextField.background", colorA);
.
.
```

some of the properties does not change. I believe UIManager.put can not override lookandfeel properties. For example, JPanel backrounds stay grey, instead of colorA.

Thanks!

Comment: Nimbus uses a bunch of keys for managing it's state, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504013/changing-the-defauls-key-values-for-jbutton-in-nimbus-laf/24504387#24504387) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379251/change-ui-lookup-for-progressbar-swing-in-nimbus-theme/24379428#24379428) just for starters

Comment: @MadProgrammer
As I said some of them do not work. Like: UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Label.background", black);
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Label.foreground", lightGray); with these commands, label background turns to black, but foreground do not turn to lightgray. They are still black. I changed almost anything I thought of to lightgray. Still does not effect foreground of the labels.

Comment: I even tried doing this in a new project. Please create a new project with a label inside a panel. I can't change label font color.

Comment: Also, 
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("textForeground", lightGray);
is not an option, because if this is set, it effects all other components. For example a textfield can not have other color then lightGrey.